# Enabling specific authentication/authorization schemes on a per-endpoint basis

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

ASP.NET has the `[Allow Anonymous]` attribute which allows you to bypass authorization on a specific endpoint. I'm wondering if there's a common way of enabling specific authentication schemes on an endpoint by endpoint basis.

Imagine you wanted to support different schemes like a `Basic` scheme and a `Bearer` scheme and so on. But you didn't want to support all schemes on all endpoints. It seems like a convenient way to do that would be to create attributes like [BasicAuth] and [BearerAuth] so you could just annotate the specific endpoints you want to enable. Looking at how AuhtorizationAttributes work, however, it seems like they behave like a logical AND rather than a logical OR.

For example, if I annotated an endpoint with both [BasicAuth] and [BearerAuth] and one returns `False` on `IsAuthorized` the whole thing would fail. This makes me think I'm either looking in the wrong place or have an uncommon use-case.

Am I looking in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

`AuthorizationAttribute` supports different kind of authorizations. It can be used to support `Policies` or `Roles`. If you want an OR kind of logic you can use the authorization attribute with a comma separated string for roles. That will let your endpoint accessible by those roles.

Use it like this for OR logic:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "HRManager,Finance")]
public class SalaryController : Controller
{
}
```

For AND logic

```
[Authorize(Roles = "PowerUser")]
[Authorize(Roles = "ControlPanelUser")]
public class ControlPanelController : Controller
{
}
```

Source is [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

---

I would recommend reading through the whole [Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2) documentation.

Comment: I was considering that option but it felt like more of a hack rather than an intended use-case. Perhaps that's the best option though.

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree with you. The other option is Policies + Claims. It is really depends on your needs.